# Excel doesn't count zero value of cell

Tags: excel, formula

Trying to discount zero value in Excel.

My formula is `=SUM(U19+X19)/2`

however if either `U19` or `X19` contain a value of zero I want the formula to be
`=SUM(U19+X19)/1` or `=SUM(U19+X19)`

Comment: You should probably use an `IF`?

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
=IF(U19*X19=0, SUM(U19+X19), SUM(U19+X19)/2)
```

or more simple:

```
=IF(U19*X19=0, U19+X19, (U19+X19)/2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use COUNTIF. You would need to call it twice since it does not accept disjoint cells.

```
=(U19 + X19) / (COUNTIF(U19,"<>0") + COUNTIF(X19,"<>0"))
```